# Analytical Solution to Laplace over Irregular Domain using DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, regions, boundary-condition-at-infinity, boundary-conditions

I would like to find an analytical solution to a Laplace equation over the following irregular domain using a mix of Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions. I've spent a lot of time trying to use dsolve to compute and analytical result with Neumann values and Dirichlet conditions and I cannot figure it out so I think I have resolved to just set x1, x2, y1, and y2 adequately large and use another Dirichlet condition to set the function value to 0 at those boundaries.

[image: Desired Region]

I implemented this in Mathematica as follows but I receive an error message from DSolveValue stating the variable specification is not valid. The only thing I can think of is the analytical solver cannot handle this irregular domain.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
buffer = 25;
x1 = -1; x2 = 1; y1 = -1; y2 = 1 ; 
Uo = 100;

(* Plot Region *)
omeg1 = Rectangle[{x1, 0}, {0, y2}];
omeg2 = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {x2, y2}];
omeg3 = Rectangle[{0, y1}, {x2, 0}];
omegp = RegionUnion[omeg1, omeg2, omeg3];
(*RegionPlot[omegp]*)

(* Solve Region *)
omeg1 = Rectangle[{-buffer, 0}, {0, buffer}];
omeg2 = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {buffer, buffer}];
omeg3 = Rectangle[{0, -buffer}, {buffer, 0}];
omegs = RegionUnion[omeg1, omeg2, omeg3];

eqn = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0;

sol = DSolveValue[{eqn,
    DirichletCondition[
     u[x, y] == Piecewise[{{Uo, x <= 0 && y <= 0}}, 0], True]},
   u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] omegs] // FullSimplify
```

So I think I need to re-frame the problem as a coupled PDE system over simple regions where the regions are linked through matched boundaries as shown below. But I have no idea how to implement this in Mathematica or how well the analytical solver will be able to handle it. Does anyone know how I can solve this problem? Am I going down the right path?

[image: Linked Regions]

Comment: Exact solution of this problem is $u(x,y)=u_0$. What actually you try to get?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the Neumann conditions along $x=x_2$ is used as an odd symmetric condition. Making the problem such that $u_0$ is the excitation on the left side of the $x=x_2$ boundary and $-u_0$ is the excitation on the right side of the $x=x_2$ boundary.

Comment: Did you try to solve your problem numerically?

Comment: Yes, exhaustively. This is a simplified version of a far more complex domain that I am interested in and I have solved in numerically extensively. I am trying to assess the possibility of solving it analytically to hopefully provide some deeper understanding of the general case of the system, without just solving it numerically thousands of times.

Comment: How did you formulate the numerical problem?

Comment: The numerical problem is formulated exactly how you see it above, less the symmetry condition along $x=x_2$. A parameter driven 2-D domain is constructed and solved using the PDE FEA toolbox in MATLAB.

Comment: Could you upload picture with $u(x,y)$ distribution over region you solved numerically?